# How can I use the params variable from AudioService.start

Tags: flutter, audio

Audioservice.start function is from the package named audio_service for Flutter, developed by Ryan Heise.
What I am trying to do is find out a way to pass information through AudioPlayerTask, which is run by AudioService.start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call **AudioService.start** method and pass your params:

```
AudioService.start(
  backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _yourTaskEntrypoint,
  params: {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"},
);
```

Or call **AudioService.customAction** for pass your params at task runtime.

Retrieve data in your task:

```
@override
Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
  print(params["key1"]);
}

@override
Future<dynamic> onCustomAction(String name, dynamic arguments) async {
  print("$name:$arguments");
}
```

See example or docs:
https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service/example
https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/latest/audio_service/AudioService/start.html

Comment: And how do I retrieved them or access them?

Comment: onStart and onCustomAction implementation in your task

Comment: and use AudioServiceBackground.sendCustomEvent to send data from task to app ui, listen to AudioService.customEventStream in ui

Comment: Thank you very much ;) God bless you!